# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

When I try to use  function inside another function

**Error**

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'

```
# Function to calculate 2D circularity ratio      
def defineCircularRatio(perim2D, area2D): 

    circularity_ratio = (4*math.pi*area2D)/(perim2D**2)

    return circularity_ratio

    print "The 2D circul_ratio is:", circularity_ratio
```

perimeter and area  -calculated by other functions.

Comment: You've listed your code and error. Now tell us what you want help with. It says in your error that is because you're doing multiplication with a float and a None object, which of course won't work. Which line is wrong? Can you please reformat and complete the last line.

Comment: `area2D` must be `None`

Answer (score 1):

This is the line that gives the error:

```
circularity_ratio = (4*math.pi*area2D)/(perim2D**2)
```

Now since it has `float` before `NoneType` in the error and `math.pi` is a float itself, this means that `perim2D` was never defined or is equal to nothing, hence `NoneType`. Declare `perim2D` as something, like an integer or a float to prevent the error. For example:

```
variable = 2
other_variable = 3

def defineCircularRatio(perim2D, area2D): 

    circularity_ratio = (4*math.pi*area2D)/(perim2D**2)

    return circularity_ratio

    print "The 2D circul_ratio is:", circularity_ratio

defineCircularRatio(variable, other_variable)
```

The above code assigns `variable` as `perim2D`, which solves the problem as `perim2D` is no longer equal to `None` but to 2. `other_variable` was used to be assigned to `area2D`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like area2D isn't a integer neither a float. Try checking if you have override its value previosly or if the function that calculate area2D truly calculate the value properly.

Answer (score 0):

Using just base sample code with your function:

```
import math

def defineCircularRatio(perim2D, area2D):
    circularity_ratio = (4*math.pi*area2D)/(perim2D**2)
    return circularity_ratio

def main ():
    area2D = input ("Enter the area: ")
    perim2D = input ("Enter the perimeter: ")
    result = defineCircularRatio(perim2D, area2D)
    print "The 2D circul_ratio is:", result

main()
```

Using this sample code, your error is all about what you are passing as area2D and perim2D. Have you tried using an IDE with breakpoints so you can see what you are passing? I use eric myself.
Your function structure seems to be fine. I would focus on how you are passing perim2D and area2D to your function.